# Removing letters from a string that occur in the previous string

Tags: python, string, function, python-3.3

I need to define a function called `remove_letters(str1,str2)` which returns a string obtained by removing from string two every letter occurring in str1

So far I have this but It doesn't remove the duplicate letters, it only removes what you put in for it to remove.

```
def remove_letters(str1,str2):
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str2:
         str2_list.remove()
         return (str2)
```

Update

I now need to test this function for a variety for strings. When called the code only returns the last result and not the first two. This is my code.

```
def test_remove_letters():
    string_list = [('sop', 'sen'),('dog', 'god'),('lighter', 'darker')]
    for str1,str2 in string_list:
        print('The original words are', str1, 'and', str2)
        return ('The result is', remove_letters(str1,str2))
```

Comment: `return ''.join(c for c in str2 if c not in str1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def remove_letters(str1,str2):
    s = set(str1)
    return "".join([char for char in str2 if char not in s])
```

Or in a loop:

```
def remove_letters(str1, str2):
    res = ""  
    s = set(str1)
    for char in str2:
        if char not in s: 
            res += char
    return res
```

Both the loop and the list comprehension have the same logic, we keep the chars in str2 that don't appear in str1.

Using your own code, you need to iterate over str2 and remove any char from str2_list that  is in str1 then use join on the list to get a string:

```
def remove_letters(str1,str2):
    str2_list = list(str2)
    for char in str2:
        if char in str1:
             str2_list.remove(char)
    return "".join(str2_list)
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you. Extension on question above. I have created a test function for this with multiple strings but when called it only returns the result of the last string and not the first two. The code i have for this i have put in question above. @padraiccunningham

Comment: move your return out of the loop. dedent four spaces

Comment: I tried that before and that achieves printing 'The original words are' for each set of strings but not for the results.

Comment: sorry thought you were returning a list, either store results in a  list and return that or just use print statements in the loop,`print ('The result is', remove_letters(str1,str2))` instead of return

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) and [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) for this:

```
>>> def remove_letters(str1,str2):
...     return str2.translate(str.maketrans('', '', str1))
...
>>> remove_letters('abc', 'aaabbbccc')
''
>>> remove_letters('abc', 'aaaxbbbycccz')
'xyz'
>>>
```

If you test this solution with [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit), you will see it is quite efficient:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>>
>>> def remove_letters(str1,str2):
...     s = set(str1)
...     return "".join([char for char in str2 if char not in s])
...
>>> timeit("remove_letters('abc', 'aaaxbbbycccz')", "from __main__ import remove_letters")
6.056879016746539
>>>
>>> def remove_letters(str1,str2):
...     return str2.translate(str.maketrans('', '', str1))
...
>>> timeit("remove_letters('abc', 'aaaxbbbycccz')", "from __main__ import remove_letters")
5.283739134443065
>>>
```